# Need to send information from checkbox to JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am new at rails. 
Here is my js file

```
$(document).on 'change', 'id1', ->
  if @checked
    calEvents = 'events.json'
    return
  else
    calEvents = 'events/user_events.json'
    return
```

And my checkbox in view file:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'id1' %>
```

It should change content of fullCalendar but it didn't. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Could you show us the generated JS?

Comment: replace `id1` with `#id1` in your coffeescript. It's an  ID and needs to be prefixed with the # so it knows to search the ID attribute of your elements

Comment: @SunnyRGupta can you tell me how? here is no any issues in dev console

Answer (score 1):

In this case, using jQuery notation, `id1` refers to a tag with that type. As pointed out in the comments you want `#id1`.

```
$(document).on 'change', '#id1', ->
  // ...
```

Comment: Are you running this inside a `$(function() { ... })` document-ready type block or are you executing it inadvertently before the page is loaded? Does `$('#id1')` in the console give you any results?

Comment: I ran it  inadvertently before the page is loaded. Does it change something?

Comment: Normally you'd write this as `$('#id1').change ->` rather than the form you have here which *should* bind against instances of `#id1` that appear in the document. Triggering your jQuery initialization after document load is almost always a good idea, though.